# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length') in Mongoose / Array is undefined / Angela Yu's Web Development Bootcamp Course

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, undefined

I'm making a todolist in browser from Angela Yu's Web Development Bootcamp Course. My problem is that when I try to start the web app from the browser (`localhost:3000`) I get the error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')
```

My code is:

```
//jshint esversion:6

const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const app = express();

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(express.static("public"));

mongoose.connect("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/todolistDB",
{
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  serverSelectionTimeoutMS: 5000
}).catch(err => console.log(err.reason));

  const itemsSchema = {
    name: String
  };

  const Item = mongoose.model("Item", itemsSchema);

  const item1 = new Item({
    name: "Welcome to your todolist!"
  });

  const item2 = new Item({
    name: "Hit the + button to add a new item."
  });

  const item3 = new Item({
    name: "<-- Hit this to delete an item."
  });

  const defaultItems = [item1, item2, item3];

app.get("/", function(req, res) {
  Item.find({}).then(function(err, foundItems){
      if(foundItems.length === 0) {
        Item.insertMany(defaultItems).then(function(err) {
          if(err) {
            console.log(err);
          } else {
            console.log("Successfully saved default items to DB!");
            console.log(defautItems);
          }
        });
        res.redirect("/");
      }
    else {
      res.render("list", {listTitle: "Today", newListItems: foundItems});
      console.log(foundItems);
    }
  });
});

app.post("/", function(req, res){
  const itemName = req.body.newItem;
  const item = new Item({[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C2viu.png)
    name: itemName
  });
  item.save();
  res.redirect("/");
});

app.get("/work", function(req,res){
  res.render("list", {listTitle: "Work List", newListItems: workItems});
});

app.get("/about", function(req, res){
  res.render("about");
});

app.listen(3000, function() {
  console.log("Server started on port 3000.");
});
```

[The error here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PTslF.png)

The error refers to the *foundItems* array which is strangely undefined. The elements of this array are stored in the MongoDB database and must be displayed in the web application todolist. But this is not happening because of the mentioned error. If the *foundItems* array does not have any items (its length is equal to zero), the items of the *defaultItems* array will be automatically added to the list when the web application is loaded in the browser. Because the "foundItems" array is undefined, the application cannot execute the statement **foundItems.length === 0**, which causes the error to occur.
Finally I mention the fact that the connection to the MongoDB server is functional and that I can store (outside the *app.get* method) the items of the "defaultItems" array in the database.

I await your answers with great interest!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably receiving another error from Mongoose on  `app.get("/", function(req, res)` function. If you change your code slightly, you'll see the real error. So replace your function `app.get("/", function(req, res)` to:

```
app.get("/", function (req, res) {
  Item.find({})
    .then(foundItems => {
      if (foundItems.length === 0) {
        Item.insertMany(defaultItems)
          .then(function () {
            console.log("Successfully saved default items to DB!");
            console.log(defaultItems);
            res.redirect("/");
          })
          .catch(function (err) {
            console.log("Error inserting default items:", err);
          });
      } else {
        res.render("list", { listTitle: "Today", newListItems: foundItems });
        console.log(foundItems);
      }
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log("Error finding items:", err);
    });
});
```

Comment: The real error:

TypeError: C:\Diverse\Probleme facultate\Aplicatii Software - Programare\Web Development\todolist-v2-starting-files\todolist-v2-starting-files\views\list.ejs:8
    6| 
    7|   <div class="box">
 >> 8|   <%  newListItems.forEach().then(function(item){  %>
    9|       <div class="item">
    10|         <input type="checkbox">
    11|         <p><%=  item.name  %></p>

undefined is not a function
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)

Comment: list.ejs:

<%- include("header") -%>

  <div class="box" id="heading">
    <h1> <%= listTitle %> </h1>
  </div>

  <div class="box">
  <%  newListItems.forEach().then(function(item){  %>
      <div class="item">
        <input type="checkbox">
        <p><%=  item.name  %></p>
      </div>
  <%  });  %>

      <form class="item" action="/" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="newItem" placeholder="New Item" autocomplete="off">
        <button type="submit" name="list">+</button>
      </form>
  </div>

<%- include("footer") -%>

Comment: Hi! Do you have any suggestions on how to modify the list.ejs file? I'm stuck here. I would be very grateful if you could help me here as well!

Answer (score 1):

so a couple of recommendations:

- Add a [mongoose schema][1]
- Change you promise chains to async/await pairs like mongoose's documentation it's easier to catch  errors
- Move the mongoose connect function into your listen function
- Don't redirect from '/' it will endlessly redirect to itself
- Create a migrate endpoint to migrate default items
- Use the route '/items' to create a new item (`POST '/items'`) and retrieve all items (`GET '/items'`) as described in [RESTful API practices][2]
- Remember to use `res.status(200)` for a succesful get, `res.status(201)` for a successful item creation, and `res.status(400)` for a bad request. These end the request.

my working version here: https://replit.com/join/ygazhrwuqj-zwiqler94

[1]: [https://mongoosejs.com/docs/index.html#:~:text=For%20brevity%2C%20let%27s,Kitten%27%2C%20kittySchema](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/index.html#:%7E:text=For%20brevity%2C%20let%27s,Kitten%27%2C%20kittySchema))%3B
[2]: https://restfulapi.net/resource-naming/

Comment: Also my personal mongoDB atlas instance expires in 5 hours so you may need to run my working version locally after that

Answer (score 0):

This is because `foundItems` might not have data all the time. You can add a check to see if foundItems is defined.

Change your `if` condition with this check before accessing the length.

```
if(!foundItems || foundItems.length === 0)
```

Comment: Hi! I modified the instruction as you recommended, but now I get another error:

MongoBulkWriteError: E11000 duplicate key error collection: todolistDB.items index: _id_ dup key: { _id: ObjectId('644fffec1e87b923774fb064')

Answer (score 0):

My list.ejs file:

```
    <%- include("header") -%>
    
      <div class="box" id="heading">
        <h1> <%= listTitle %> </h1>
      </div>
    
      <div class="box">
      <%  newListItems.forEach().then(function(item){  %>
          <div class="item">
            <input type="checkbox">
            <p><%=  item.name  %></p>
          </div>
      <%  });  %>
    
          <form class="item" action="/" method="post">
            <input type="text" name="newItem" placeholder="New Item" autocomplete="off">
            <button type="submit" name="list">+</button>
          </form>
      </div>
    
    <%- include("footer") -%>
```

My new real error (in list.ejs file):

```
TypeError: C:\Diverse\Probleme facultate\Aplicatii Software - Programare\Web Development\todolist-v2-starting-files\todolist-v2-starting-files\views\list.ejs:8
    6| 
    7|   <div class="box">
 >> 8|   <%  newListItems.forEach().then(function(item){  %>
    9|       <div class="item">
    10|         <input type="checkbox">
    11|         <p><%=  item.name  %></p>

undefined is not a function
```

The new list.ejs file code:

```
<%- include("header") -%>

  <div class="box" id="heading">
    <h1> <%= listTitle %> </h1>
  </div>

  <div class="box">
  <%  newListItems.forEach(item => { %>
      <div class="item">
        <input type="checkbox">
        <p><%=  item.name  %></p>
      </div>
  <%  });  %>

      <form class="item" action="/" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="newItem" placeholder="New Item" autocomplete="off">
        <button type="submit" name="list">+</button>
      </form>
  </div>

<%- include("footer") -%>
```

Now the whole code works perfectly! The web app in the browser is loading properly! Thank you all for your help and advice!